# Как создать разрушаемый terrain как в игре worms?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Недавно начал использовать framework libgdx с подтдержкой движка box2d. Стоит задача создать разрушаемость объектов как в червяках. Перерыл google однако прямого решения так и не нашёл. Прошу помощи или хотя бы напоавьте в нужное русло. 
Ps
Для создания карт использую tile map editor

Answer (score 0):

Tiled Map Editor скорее всего вам не подойдёт. В Worms нет разделения на collision боксы и картинку, всё - просто картинка, а где пиксели картинок накладываются, там и коллижн. То есть, возьмем, например, штуку, через которую можно прожигать тоннели. В то время, как червь идет вправо в землю, каждую итерацию игрового цикла проверяется, с какими пикселями сталкиваются пиксели бурилки. Те пиксели и уничтожаются.

Если сравнивать с Tiled Map Editor, то тут получается тайл = пиксель.

Вот тут люди обсуждают, как работает worms, если интересно: https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/593329